# Update a float to null?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have this stored Procedure in MS SQL2008 (C#)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE UpdateProducts
@ProductID INT, @Name nvarchar(50), @Length Float
AS
UPDATE       Product
SET          Name = @Name, Length = @Length
WHERE        (ProductID = @ProductID)
```

Length are in some cases "" (nothing). But when "" is inserted the value 0 is inserted instead. I want the value to be null. How can I do that? This did not work:

```
if (Length == "")
{
   Length = null;            
}
```

Comment: Is the field nullable? By the way, "" is not nothing, unless you don't mean the VB meaning of nothing.

Comment: You didn't show us the Size declaration in C#, and it's name is different from the Length parameter in the stored procedure. Howewver: `Length = NULLIF(@Length, 0)`

Comment: Sorry, Length it is... Yes the field is nullable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the defaults to `NULL` in the proc and you dont have to explicity pass `NULL` to a proc.

```
CREATE PROC ..dbo.Proc ( @param1 int =NULL, @param2 varchar(40) = NULL ,etc)
```

Also, if you have to send NULL from your app you would use `DBNull.Value`

Comment: Great that did the job! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try [`DBNull.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value.aspx):

```
if (Size == "")
{
   Size = DBNull.Value;
}
```

and make sure your database column is nullable.

Comment: I get this then: Error 1 Can not convert type System.DBNull to string

Comment: @user1007103, change the type of `Size` to `object` or assign the `SqlParameter` value directly to `DBNull.Value` if the string is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Use [NULLIF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx)

```
UPDATE       Product
SET          Name = @Name, Length = NULLIF(@Length, '')
WHERE        (ProductID = @ProductID)
```

- Empty string is implicitly cast to 0 for float and int. decimal gives an error
- Empty string and NULL are different

Edit: this deals with unclean input, so you don't have to worry about it...

Comment: I still get the Value 0 in Length